# getting trouble to add datepicker plugin in my phonegap application

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, cordova, datepicker

I am trying to add datepicker plugin in my phonegap application.
I created phonegap application using the eclipse.
Steps :-
       1) First i created the android project in eclipse
       2) After i added the cordova.js and cordova.jar file to project and converted that project to the phonegap project.

Now project is working fine.
But when i am trying to add datepicker plugin to the application using "cordova plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker"
I am getting error

```
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

and when i am trying to add using "phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker"
I am getting error

```
[Error: project directory could not be found]
   [error] project directory could not be found
```

I dont know what problem i am getting here.
How can i add datepicker plugin manually using the eclipse.
My project structure is [image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying with cordova version 1.6!!! It's too old, now cordova version is 3.5 as of today.

Here is the up to date documentation [link for 3.5](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/).

For starters, there are no more plugins.xml file in cordova.

You should create the project using command line cordova commands (introduced after 3.0 as far as I remember) so that folder structures and config.xml file (plugins and other configurations are in here), etc, are also formed. Doing it manually is almost impossible imho.

That's why you are getting error about working directory. I am confused and surprised that you are getting some error message at all.

Comment: By using command line i created the project, and tried to use the datepicker using cordova plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker but still its showing the same error Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

Answer (score 0):

do you add from command line ? if yes/ check the path, maybe you aren't in the project path,

if you were in the parent folder of the project root, the command not work.
for example:

```
c:\phonegap-projects\cordova add something
```

above command isn't work. you must be in the Cordova project path:

```
c:\phonegap-projects\MyApp\cordova add something
```

also you can check with this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker
```

hope be useful.

Comment: @Gaurav did you test adding plugin to other projects ?
and do you try with this :
"cordova plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker"

Comment: @Gaurav i test like you.
i have same problem if i use "phonegap local plugin add ..." and solved when i user "cordova plugin add ..."

Comment: but its not getting solved. i created the cordova project using command line,,,,,, still it showing the Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

Comment: try to make a empty folder named ".cordova" in the project root path.
to do this run this command from command line:
md .cordova.

be sure to put dot to start and end of the folder name .